# why my string cant be modified using index addressing

Tags: c++, string

when i modify the postifix string with index `[]` it does not change the string but
using operator such as `+=` it modifies the string successfully

```
void  InToPost(string infix)
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    
    int len=infix.size();
    string postfix;
    
    while(infix[i]!='\0')
    { 
        cout<<postfix<<endl;   
        if(isOperand(infix[i]))

         postfix[j++]=infix[i++];//Here is the problem

         
         else
         {
           if(precedence(infix[i])>precedence(top->data))
           
               push(infix[i++]);
                    
            else
            {
               postfix[j++]= pop(); //Here is the problem
                
            }
            
            
         }      
        
    }

    
    while(top!=NULL)
        postfix[j++]= pop(); //Here is the problem
        

    
    cout<<postfix;//Here i am outputting the string  
}
```

It will work for expression like postfix += infix[i++]

Answer (score 4):

You can't just extend a `std::string` by writing to an index off the end of it (and shouldn't overwrite the terminating null either, which is automatically put at `[0]` for an empty `string`): i.e. `postfix[j++] = xxx;` is broken.  Try `postfix += infix[i++];` (or whatever you want to append) instead: when you do that, it checks for sufficient capacity (i.e. reserved memory) getting more memory if needed, and tracks the additional characters such that `.size()` then counts them, and reestablishes a null terminator after the textual content.